# unmet dependencies during apt installation

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I installed a package using apt,I encountered the below problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby2.3-dev : Breaks: ruby2.3-dev:i386 (!= 2.3.1-2~16.04.12) but 2.3.0-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
 ruby2.3-dev:i386 : Depends: libgmp-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libruby2.3:i386 (= 2.3.0-5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Breaks: ruby2.3-dev (!= 2.3.0-5ubuntu1) but 2.3.1-2~16.04.12 is to be installed
```

I have no idea what happened. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that 64bit and 32bit packages are conflicting with the ruby installation. Try and temporarily remove i386 from your package manager and try and install it with apt again. Refer to https://superuser.com/questions/714391/how-do-i-remove-all-i386-architecture-packages-from-my-debian-installation for a guide.